# Install dll into the gac + .net 4.0

Tags: .net-4.0, .net-assembly, gacutil

I want to add some .net 4.0 dlls to the gac, I know that the new gac is **C:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\assembly**

I cannot use the **gacutil** because visual studio in not installed on the deployment machine, and i cannot simply drag/drop the dll to the folder as i usually do in the previous versions.

How can I install the dlls to the GAC.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

It is part of Windows SDK and can be download separately at http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6B6C21D2-2006-4AFA-9702-529FA782D63B. This installation will have gacutil.exe included. But first check it here: C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin you might have it installed

[where is gacutil.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397479/where-is-gacutil-exe)

UPDATE : Modified the link. Windows SDK for .Net 4.0

Comment: it is giving me this error Failure adding assembly to the cache:   This assembly is built by a runtime newe
r than the currently loaded runtime and cannot be loaded.

Comment: Modified the answer : http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/en/details.aspx?FamilyID=6B6C21D2-2006-4AFA-9702-529FA782D63B

Answer (score -1):

Using Microsoft Installer Package. You can get download of installer from
http://www.microsoft.com.

I am not confirmed but ideally Gacutil must be part of framework and you can find it out in .net framework folder