# Why can't I encrypt web.config/appSettings using a custom configProtectionProvider on Azure (Windows Server 2012)?

Tags: encryption, azure, web-config, appsettings, windows-server-2012

I have an MVC application which is deployed to a Windows Azure hosted service running on a Windows Server 2012 virtual machine. In the `web.config` file, I have 3 sections encrypted [using the `PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider`](http://archive.msdn.microsoft.com/pkcs12protectedconfg): `connectionStrings`, `dataCacheClients`, and `system.net/mailSettings/smtp`. Here is what the relevant sections look like:

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <configProtectedData>
    <providers>
      <add name="CustomProvider" thumbprint="[this is secret]"
          type="Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider, PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=34da007ac91f901d" />
    </providers>
  </configProtectedData>
  ...
  <connectionStrings configProtectionProvider="CustomProvider">
    <EncryptedData ... ommitted for brevity
  </connectionStrings>
  ...
  <system.net>
    <mailSettings>
      <smtp configProtectionProvider="CustomProvider">
        <EncryptedData ommitted for brevity
      </smtp>
    </mailSettings>
  </system.net>
  ...
  <dataCacheClients configProtectionProvider="CustomProvider">
    <EncryptedData ommitted for brevity
  </dataCacheClients>
  ...
</configuration>
```

**All of the above works perfectly fine**. When deployed to Azure, the connection strings, SMTP mail, and data cache all work. The `PKCS12ProtectedConfiguration` provider uses my custom certificate to decrypt the sections and all is well.

However I can't seem to use the same approach to encrypt `web.config/appSettings`. When I try deploying something like the following to Azure...

```
<configuration>
  ...
  <appSettings configProtectionProvider="CustomProvider">
    <EncryptedData ommitted for brevity
  </appSettings>
  ...
</configuration>
```

...then I get the following exception:

```
Server Error in '/' Application.

Configuration Error

Description: An error occurred during the processing of a configuration file
required to service this request. Please review the specific error details
below and modify your configuration file appropriately.

Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Could not
load file or assembly 'PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=34da007ac91f901d' or one of its dependencies.
The system cannot find the file specified.

Source Error: 

Line 41:     </EncryptedData>
Line 42:   </connectionStrings>
Line 43:   <appSettings configProtectionProvider="CustomProvider">
Line 44:     <EncryptedData ...>
Line 45:       <EncryptionMethod .../>

Source File: E:\sitesroot\0\web.config    Line: 43 

Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why
the assembly 'PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider, Version=1.0.0.0,
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=34da007ac91f901d' could not be loaded.

WRN: Assembly binding logging is turned OFF.
To enable assembly bind failure logging, set the registry value
[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog] (DWORD) to 1.
Note: There is some performance penalty associated with assembly bind failure
logging.
To turn this feature off, remove the registry value
[HKLM\Software\Microsoft\Fusion!EnableLog].
```

**However I know the `PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.dll` is in the `/bin` folder** because:

1. I remoted into the VM and saw it in both `approot/bin` and `siteroot/bin`
2. When I deploy with the `appSettings` unencrypted, the other 3 sections are successfully decrypted using this dll.

It's almost as if the assembly loader can't look for the `PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.dll` file until after it parses and loads the `appSettings` section. I have tried omitting the Version, Culture, and PublicKeyToken parts of the provider config section, but then the error just changes to this:

```
Parser Error Message: An error occurred loading a configuration file: Could not 
load file or assembly 'PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider' or one of its 
dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.
```

**Is it possible to encrypt `web.config/appSettings` using a custom `configProtectionProvider` when deploying to a Windows Azure hosted service running on a Windows Server 2012 virtual machine?** If so, what am I missing here?

### Update:

After posting this I turned on the `Fusion!EnableLog` registry key and now I get this additional information in the exception:

```
Assembly Load Trace: The following information can be helpful to determine why
the assembly 'PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, 
Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=34da007ac91f901d' could not be loaded.

=== Pre-bind state information ===
LOG: User = NT AUTHORITY\NETWORK SERVICE
LOG: DisplayName = PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=34da007ac91f901d
 (Fully-specified)
LOG: Appbase = file:///d:/windows/system32/inetsrv/
LOG: Initial PrivatePath = NULL
Calling assembly : (Unknown).
===
LOG: This bind starts in default load context.
LOG: No application configuration file found.
LOG: Using host configuration file: D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\aspnet.config
LOG: Using machine configuration file from D:\Windows\Microsoft.NET\Framework64\v4.0.30319\config\machine.config.
LOG: Post-policy reference: PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider, Version=1.0.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=34da007ac91f901d
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///d:/windows/system32/inetsrv/PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///d:/windows/system32/inetsrv/PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider/PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.DLL.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///d:/windows/system32/inetsrv/PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.EXE.
LOG: Attempting download of new URL file:///d:/windows/system32/inetsrv/PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider/PKCS12ProtectedConfigurationProvider.EXE.
```

**So here's another question**: Why is IIS looking in the `inetsrv` path for this assembly instead of looking for it in the app's `/bin` folder? I see in the log "No application configuration file found." Does this mean the assembly binder has to find a `web.config` with an unencrypted `appSettings` section in order to parse and load it?

Comment: Did you attempt installing the assembly in the GAC yet on role start?

Comment: @Zonder no. Can that be done with an azure startup cmd? I am no good at writing windows commands...

Comment: I found a blog article explaining he process http://blogs.infosupport.com/adding-assemblies-to-the-gac-in-windows-azure/

Comment: Don't forget to sign your assembly :)

Comment: @Dreamwalker that did the trick, thanks. Please post this as an answer so that I can reward you with the bounty. Also, assembly-signing was not necessary.

Comment: great news glad it was just that I have had a similar problem with WCF before that's what got my attention

Comment: I'm getting same behavior on normal IIS MVC site (not Azure).  It all worked in MVC2, but since MVC3 onward, I get same error.  Suggest same thing?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Did you attempt installing the assembly in the GAC yet on role start?

Information on adding assemblies to the gac on start up http://blogs.infosupport.com/adding-assemblies-to-the-gac-in-windows-azure/

Comment: To help future readers: [here's](http://stackoverflow.com/q/3397479/29) where `gacutil` is hiding

Answer (score 0):

I was able to fix this error by installing the NuGet package: https://www.nuget.org/packages/Pkcs12ProtectedConfigurationProvider/

I'm guessing part of the install process is registering the .dll for you.