# Visual Studio 2013 Premium solution load errors after Update 3

Tags: azure, visual-studio-2013, updates, microsoft-web-deploy

I installed VS2013Update 3 and now I get errors when opening an solution:

The 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.WebPublishPackage,MircosoftVisualStudio.Web.Publish' package did not load correctly.

And

The 'ScaffoldungVSPackage' package did not load correctly.

The outcome of this is that I can't open the Publish-Dialog and there are no templates when creating a new Webproject.

In the activitylog are following errors:

```
<entry>
<record>447</record>
<time>2014/08/05 14:27:31.859</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>End package load [Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.WebPublishPackage, Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish]</description>
<guid>{1AD387FC-B1E8-4023-91FE-F22260B661DB}</guid>
<hr>80131522</hr>
<errorinfo>Could not load type 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Internal.Contracts.Publish.IVsWebJobPublishService' from assembly 'Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Internal.Contracts, Version=2.3.0.0, Culture=neutral, PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a'.</errorinfo>
</entry>

<entry>
<record>450</record>
<time>2014/08/05 14:31:20.199</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>SetSite failed for package [ScaffoldingVsPackage]</description>
<guid>{FAA496BF-FB16-4671-B3D5-E4B388A18478}</guid>
<hr>80131500</hr>
<errorinfo>Cannot cast the underlying exported value of type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Templating.ScaffoldingAssemblyDirectiveProcessor (ContractName="Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.IServiceRegistrar")' to type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.IServiceRegistrar'.</errorinfo>
</entry>
<entry>
<record>451</record>
<time>2014/08/05 14:31:20.199</time>
<type>Error</type>
<source>VisualStudio</source>
<description>End package load [ScaffoldingVsPackage]</description>
<guid>{FAA496BF-FB16-4671-B3D5-E4B388A18478}</guid>
<hr>80131500</hr>
<errorinfo>Cannot cast the underlying exported value of type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.Templating.ScaffoldingAssemblyDirectiveProcessor (ContractName="Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.IServiceRegistrar")' to type 'Microsoft.AspNet.Scaffolding.IServiceRegistrar'.</errorinfo>
</entry>
```

Has anyone an idea how to resolve this issue? I already tried:

- Reinstalling VS2013
- Reinstallung Update 3
- Reinstalling WindowsAzureSDK V2.4
- Disabling Extensions
- run /devenv setup /devenv updateconfiguration
- Delete Appdatafiles

Thanks!

Answer (score 12, accepted):

the following solution from the asp.net-forums worked for me:

> the solution was to reset the assemblies for Contract and Publishing using the Developer command prompt as Administrator  If you have used the default installation setting then this is probably the path
>
> gacutil -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Publish.dll"
>
> gacutil -i "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\Extensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Internal.Contracts.dll"

here is the link:
http://forums.asp.net/p/2000916/5751509.aspx?p=True&t=635430085558824221&pagenum=1

Comment: The path for express is "...\IDE\VWDExpressExtensions\Microsoft\Web Tools\Publish\". It solved the issue for existing projects, but the project templates are still missing. Reinstalling Update 3 doesn't help (uninstalling does).

Comment: i found an update from a ms employer for the template issue: -- update, we're still investigating the problem, we cannot repro it in our lab machine yet.  The issue above is fixed by the reporter after uninstalling VS2013, removed the left over folder in %program files(x86)%, reinstalled VS2013, and re-applied VS2013 update 3.  Please contact me for the same problem you are experiencing.  We will ask for some diagnostic files from your computer.  Thanks.

Comment: I got a workaround from ms:1.            Close VS.  Goto C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft Visual Studio 12.0\Common7\IDE\PrivateAssemblies, delete the following assemblies if they exist:
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Contracts.dll 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Explorer.dll 
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.Internal.Contracts.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.Impl.dll
Microsoft.VisualStudio.Web.WindowsAzure.pkgdef
2.            Start VS2013 with update 3, try to create a ASP.NET Web application, see if the template exists and project can be created successfully.

Answer (score 1):

I resolved the issue by downloading the assemblies and restarting VS2013 update 5

https://www.microsoft.com/en-us/download/details.aspx?id=43709