# Register DLL in GAC -Visual Studio 2013 Add-in

Tags: biztalk, gac, biztalk-2013, dllregistration

Does anyone know a competitor to BiztalkNOS to register a c# library dll into the GAC, directly from Visual Studio 2013?

NOS is $499, and I hope there is an alternative.

Comment: Have you just tried having a post build event on your projects that calls gacutil?

Answer (score 5):

I have been using this method for years now, over multiple versions of Visual Studio. You just need to know the path gacutil.exe is stored at (see <yourpath>).
For the default path, check out: [where is gacutil.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397479/where-is-gacutil-exe)

In VS, go to Tools -> External Tools, click on Add, and enter a

- Title, for example "GAC assembly"
- Command  :   <yourpath>\gacutil.exe
- Argument: /i $(TargetPath)
- Initial directory: $(TargetDir)

... and click apply.
       
When you build a project and you want to add the assembly to the GAC, just have the project highlighted/selected in the solution explorer, and click Tools --> GAC assembly and that's it, it's "GAC'ed".

This will let you have manual control over when you GAC a DLL.
A post-build script (other answers) adds it to the GAC every time: a valid option, this is just another possibility I wanted to point out.

Answer (score 4):

You don't need any add-ins, the Windows SDK (comes with Visual Studio) provides gacutil.exe for exactly this purpose.

You can use something like this is a Post Build script:

```
CALL "%VS110COMNTOOLS%vsvars32.bat"
gacutil.exe /i "$(TargetPath)"
```

VS110 is the Visual Studio version which you may need to adjust for you local version.

Answer (score 2):

This is not exactly the same purpose, but have a look at BizTalk Deployment Framework (https://biztalkdeployment.codeplex.com/). With some work, you would be able to deploy your BizTalk Application with only one script. Your librairies will be installed directly to the GAC.

Comment: BTDF also has a handy button to GAC the DLL of the current project.  It strangely looks like a database icon on the toolbar.

Answer (score 1):

Here's what we use:

```
"C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v8.0A\bin\NETFX 4.0 Tools\gacutil.exe" /if "$(TargetFileName)"
```

Put that in your projects *Properties --> Build Events --> Post-build event command line* and it will be deployed to the GAC when you build.

This is Visual Studio 2012/BizTalk 2013