# Where is gacutil.exe? Not where it used to be

Tags: visual-studio, ssis

We have SSIS packages with custom components.  Gacutil is required to load the custom components on my new computer.

At one time, gacutil could be found here:  C:\Program Files\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v6.0A\bin

According to:  [where is gacutil.exe?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3397479/where-is-gacutil-exe)

I have installed .NET 6 SDK and the outdated .NET 5 SDK.  Both are installed to a different folder:  Program Files\dotnet.  And, gacutil is not installed.  And the Windows SDKs folder is not created.

Every reference I find in stackoverflow and other locations is typically 10 or 11 years old.  I believe I found some references from 2017.

Any thoughts on how to find gacutil.exe?

====================

Technical details. Using antiques.

1. SQL Server 2014
2. SSIS Visual Studio 15 ( Tools for Applications 15)
3. Component developed 2016/2017.  Most likely .NET Framework 4.5

====================

UPDATE:
I attempted install of .NET Framework SDK 4.8 as noted in answer below.  Failed with

```
.NET Framework 4.8 or a later update is already installed on this computer.
```

As noted in my original question, no folder named Microsoft SDKs exists.

Comment: .NET 5/6 are .NET *Core* 5/6. .NET Core doesn't have a Global Assembly Cache. They aren't part of the Windows SDK either. The last version of .NET Framework was 4.8. The 11 year old references you found are correct

Comment: Why are you asking? What are you trying to do? SSIS and SQL Server only work with .NET Framework and even then, only with a subset of features.

Comment: RE: "Why are you asking".   As noted in the question, we have packages with custom components that require gacutil.exe to install on my new laptop.

Comment: SSIS packages? Those only use .NET Framework, not .NET Core. The specific version depends on the SQL Server version. You can add 4.8 but your packages will still target that version, which means you'll only be able to use the C# version that matches that SDK and deploy assemblies that match that SDK. Put the relevant information in the question itself. SQL Server version, SSIS version, the version those SSIS packages target.

Comment: Technical details added to original question.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The gacutil.exe utility is included in the .NET Framework SDK. The latest being the .NET 4.8 SDK (aka developer pack) which can be downloaded from here:

https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download/dotnet-framework/net48

Upon installation, you should find it under a directory similar to: "C:\Program Files (x86)\Microsoft SDKs\Windows\v10.0A\bin\NETFX 4.8 Tools\x64"

Note, .NET 6 and .NET 5 are newer versions of dotnet core, which are cross platform compatible versions of dotnet, and do not support the Global Assembly Cache concept.

Comment: I upvoted because it probably would work if it would install. Install stops because " .NET Framework 4.8 or a later update is already installed on this computer."  There is no Program Files\Windows SDKs folder available.